# ¿Cómo puedo modificar los bordes de un JFrame?

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

Estoy haciendo un menú de login y quiero personalizarlo todo lo que pueda. El problema es que no encuentro cómo modificar los bordes alrededor de la ventana (los bordes color verde de Windows):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con setUndecorated puedo simplemente eliminar eso, pero al minimizar la pantalla se genera un bug que pone visible muy brevemente los bordes que se supone deberían ocultarse con setUndecorated, y no me gusta.

```
public void configureProperties(int width, int height) {
    this.window.setUndecorated(true);
    this.window.setSize(width, height);
    this.window.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    this.window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.window.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
}
```

Comment: Tienes el serVisible antes que la configuración de las propiedades de la ventana?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba estos métodos a ver si te ayudan:

```
dispose();
setUndecorated(true);
setVisible(true);
```

Tu código quedaría así:

```
public void configureProperties(int width, int height) {
    this.window.dispose();
    this.window.setUndecorated(true);
    this.window.setVisible(true);
    this.window.setSize(width, height);
    this.window.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    this.window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.window.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
}
```